# C# Variables connection

Tags: c#, variables, reference

Doing something like this

```
public Multime<T> Difference(Multime<T> list)
{
    Multime<T> diff = new Multime<T>();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Multisets.Count() - 1; i++)
    {
        foreach (T el in list.multiSets[i].Multimea)
        {
            if (!(list.multiSets[i + 1].Multimea.Exists(element => EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(element, el))))
                diff.Multimea.Add(el);

        }
        list.multiSets[i + 1] = diff;
        if (i < list.multiSets.Count() - 1)
            diff.Multimea.RemoveAll(item => EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(item, item));
    }
...
```

after `diff.Multimea.RemoveAll(item => EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(item, item));`
the `list.multiSets[i + 1]` is cleared too.  How can i resolve this, so that they wont be connected this way, I dont want `list.multiSets[i + 1]` to be cleared.

```
public Multime<T> this[int index]
{
    get { return this.multiSets[index]; }
    set { this.multiSets[index] = value; }
}
```

this is the indexer if it helps :)

Comment: I edited this question a little- let me know if I made any mistakes in clearing it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't want `list.multiSets[i+1]` to be cleared too.

You'll have to fill it with a copy:

```
//list.multiSets[i + 1] = diff;
  list.multiSets[i + 1] = diff.ToList();
```

Your `diff` and `list.multiSets[x]` values are *reference types*. This means that you original assignment only copies a reference to a list, not the list itself. `ToList()` is a compact way of making a clone of the list.